# Leviathan Wakes - Protogen experiment on Eros

Tags: leviathan-wakes, the-expanse-novels

Why did they have to make the experiment on humans? Couldn't they have done it with animals first?

Comment: Perhaps they did, just not in the story?

Comment: Also, where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Protogen did test it on animals first. Dresden mentions this offhand in the corporate video that the *Rocinante* crew watch aboard *Anubis*, the Protogen ship that boarded the *Scopuli* (this is location 5565 in the Kindle book):

> “The protomolecule first caught our interest for its ability to maintain its primary structure in a wide variety of conditions through secondary and tertiary changes. It also showed an affinity for carbon and silicon structures. Its activity suggested it was not in itself a living thing, but a set of free-floating instructions designed to adapt to and guide other replicating systems. Animal experiments suggest that its effects are not exclusive to simple replicators, but are, in fact, scalable.”
>
> “Animal tests,” Miller said. “What, they dumped it on a cat?”

They discovered the protomolecule two years before the Eros experiment, so it's safe to assume they tested it a lot in those years and felt that human experiments (on a large scale, to create a hive mind) was the logical next step.